# c++ references - Is there Memory Allocated?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

Consider

1.

```
MyClass &myRef;
```

In This declaration is there memory allocated for myRef?
What is the syntax of finding out the address of myRef?

2.
Then if I do

```
myRef = someOtherRefToTheSameClass
```

Who is responsible for the implementation of this assignment?

Comment: First off `MyClass &myRef;` will not compile.  If you are asking if a reference takes up space then see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521116/how-are-references-encoded-in-c

Comment: MyClass &_foo;
This DOES compile?

Comment: @OneGuyInDc `MyClass &myRef;` would compile inside a class declaration but would need to be initialized in a constructor's initializer-list. Otherwise, a reference must always be initialized at the point of declaration. A reference cannot be re-assigned.

Answer (score 1):

References don't have an address. A reference is essentially a label for another variable, and if you take the address of a reference, you'll get the address of the thing it references.

Consider:

```
void function (bool b, int x, int y)
{
    int& ref = b ? x : y;
```

Here, `&ref` will evaluate to either the same thing as `&x` or the same thing as `&y`, depending on the value of `b`.

When you use a reference on the left side of an assignment, it acts the same as if you used the underlying variable. So if you have:

```
void function (SomeClass y)
{
    SomeClass &z (y);
```

Now, since `z` is a reference to `y`, `y = foo();` and `z = foo();` do the same thing.

Comment: This does not answer either part of the question.

Comment: @cdonner I guess we understand the question differently. I understand the question as basically, "I don't understand references and so these seem like the right questions to ask", so I gave the OP enough information about how references work so that those questions no longer make sense to ask.

Comment: Fair enough. It wasn't clear what the OP wanted to achieve.