# how to give a string as parameter to be inserted in a QStringListModel

Tags: c++, qt, qstringlistmodel

am learning QT and am trying to populate a `QStringList` with a couple of elements that later populate a `QListView`

my first try from the docu was:

```
// Create model
model = new QStringListModel(this);

// Make data
List << "Java" << "C++" << "C";
// Populate our model
model->setStringList(List);
// Glue model and view together
ui->listView->setModel(model);
```

so far so good... I can see my List with all the elements I populate...

now in the same class where am doing that am trying to now defined a function that let me add new elements to the list...

so my 1st idea was defining something like

```
void MainWindow::addNewLanguage(QString& item)
{
    List << item;
    model->setStringList(List);
}
```

but(and here comes my question...)   I am only able to call my function by doing

```
QString x( "Php" );
w1.addNewLanguage( x );
```

I would like to instead dom something more nice like:

```
w1.addNewLanguage( "Pascal" );
```

no need to define a new object of the QString...

but doing that breaks the compilation with the msg

> C:\Users\xxx\WorspaceQT\untitled4\main.cpp:25: error: invalid
>   initialization of non-const reference of type 'QString&' from an
>   rvalue of type 'QString'
>        w1.addNewLanguage( "x2" );
>                           ^

anything I can do to address this??

thanks! :)

Comment: change `void MainWindow::addNewLanguage(QString& item)` to `void MainWindow::addNewLanguage(const QString& item)`

Comment: it does not work because Pascal is not a new language :P Joking aside, here you can find an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826897/why-not-non-const-reference-to-temporary-objects

Comment: @Firewall-Alien Try to construct a minimal question avoiding all irrelevant information (`QStringList`, ...), see [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The error message already gives you a great hint:

> invalid initialization of **non-const reference** of type 'QString&' from an rvalue of type 'QString'

Therefore, you should define `addNewLanguage` as:

```
void MainWindow::addNewLanguage(const QString& item)
```

or alternatively:

```
void MainWindow::addNewLanguage(QString item)
```

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826897/why-not-non-const-reference-to-temporary-objects) for an explanation why a non-const reference is not allowed to a temporary object.

Note that the second approach is not (much) slower than the first one as [`QString` is implicitly shared](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-5).