# cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int &'

Tags: c++

I'm getting the next error and I cannot find the reason for it:

> Error C2664   'void SumID<long>::operator ()<int>(G &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int &'

Why is passing an int by reference problematic?

I have the next class:

```
template <class T>
class SumID {
private:
    T sumid;

public:
    SumID():sumid()
    {
    }

    SumID(T s)
    {
        sumid = s;
    }

    T getSumID()
    {
        cout << "inside getSum";
        return sumid;
    }

    template <class G>
    void operator() (G& a)
    {
        sumid = sumid+ a;
    }
};
```

my main :

```
SumID<long> s;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    s(5); // <-- error here
```

Comment: You can do it, if you put it in a variable. Just `5` is a constant value and cannot be assigned to.

Comment: What does `5 = 17;` mean?  That's why it is an error.

Comment: Use an rvalue reference `G&& a` to bind to temporaries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When use `s(5);` the argument, 5, is not an *lvalue*. Hence, it cannot be used when the argument type is `G&`.

You can resolve the problem using one or both of the following approaches.

1. Create a variable and use it in the call.

   ```
   int x = 5;
   s(x);
   ```
2. Change the argument type to just `G`, `G&&` or `G const&`.

   ```
   template <class G>
   void operator() (G a)  // Or (G&& a) or (G const& a)
   {
      sumid = sumid+ a;
   }
   ```

Comment: or  argument type as *rvalue* : `void operator() (G&& a)`

Comment: @JeJo, or that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: So in c++ when I'm passing an lvalue I cant pass the variable by reference ? Why then setting the parameter`s type to G&& also solves the problem?

Comment: Moreover the solution G &a const raised the same error.

Comment: @JeyJ `s(5)` passes rvalue. And it cannot be bound to non-const reference (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826897/why-not-non-const-reference-to-temporary-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1  ). `s(const G&)` works because its const and `s(G&&)` works, because it's not rvalue reference but a universal reference (https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) with special rules.