# C++ 2440 error - compiler thinks string is const char?

Tags: c++, string, class, char, constants

So I have this little snippet where it thinks "abc" isn't a string but rather a const char [4], and so I can't assign it to my object. I've searched but haven't found any working solutions. Thanks in advance.

```
Tekst t = "abc";
```

```
Tekst Tekst::operator=(std::string& _text){
    return Tekst(_text);
}
```

Edit: since this is a major staple of almost every exercise in my Object Oriented Programming class, due to whatever reasons, we can't change anything that's in `int main()`, so changing `Tekst t = "abc";` is a no-go.

Edit 2:`Tekst(std::string _text) :text(_text) {};`

Comment: Your `operator=` doesn't look right. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) how to do it properly.

Comment: "_where it thinks "abc" isn't a string but rather a const char [4]_" It doesn't "think" that it is. `"abc"` is, in fact, of type `const char [4]`. Why do you think, that it should be `std::string`?

Comment: Also, can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58825457/edit) and post the construction codes for `Tekst`?

Comment: How about providing `operator=(const char*)`?

Comment: Also, related [Why not non-const reference to temporary objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826897/why-not-non-const-reference-to-temporary-objects). TLDR: If you took the argument with `const` reference: `Tekst Tekst::operator=(std::string const& _text)` it would've compiled.

Comment: Per edit 1, I'm not saying you should `main()` should be edited, I'm saying that the way you are implementing `operator=()` looks wrong. The link I shared shows how to do it properly (at least, I believe it should. There's a lot of information there, so maybe I should find it.)

Comment: Algirdas, it still compiles with the same error C2440.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiler doesn't *think* `"abc"` is a `const char [4]`. It is `const char [4]` and you think that it should be `std::string`, which is not correct. `std::string` can be implicitly constructed from `const char *`, but they are nowhere near the same.

You problem is actually that you're trying to **bind a temporary** to a **non-const reference**, which is impossible in C++. You should change the definition of your operator to

```
Tekst Tekst::operator=(const std::string& _text){
//                     ^ const here
    return Tekst(_text);
}
```

This will make your operator *technically valid* (as in, it compiles and there is no Undefined Behaviour). However, it does something very non intuitive. Consider the following:

```
Tekst t;
t = "abc";
```

In this example, `t` will not have any `"abc"` inside. The newly returned object is discarded and `t` is unchanged.

Most likely, your operator should look like this:

```
Tekst& Tekst::operator=(const std::string& _text){
    this->text = _text; //or however you want to change your object
    return *this;
}
```

Refer to [the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading?rq=1) for more information about what is and what isn't expected in each operator.

---

On a semi-related note, you *can* have `std::string` from literal in C++14 and up:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std::string_literals;

int main() {
    auto myString = "abc"s; 
    //myString is of type std::string, not const char [4]
}
```

However, this wouldn't help with your case, because the main problem was binding a temporary to non-const reference.

Comment: Even using ```const std::string&``` fails it with the same error C2440.

Comment: @Baltr That's on your constructor though, not `operator=`

Comment: @Baltr You have to show your constructor for that, but as a 80% guess you need to give it a parameter `const std::string&` as well.

Comment: Changed the constructor to ```Tekst(const std::string& _text) :text(_text) {};``` and still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ted Lyngmo, "This should help: godbolt.org/z/j_RTHu", turns out all i had to do was add a separate constructor for taking in const char*

`Tekst(const char* cstr) : Tekst(std::string(cstr)) {}`

Comment: That's not an answer to your question though. @Yksisarvinen's answer was.

Comment: I tried doing what he told me, it didn't work, so I guess I didn't figure it out well enough.

Comment: The extra constructor is another converting constructor, just like `Tekst(const std::string&);` is. When using the `Tekst t = "abc";` syntax it can only try one implicit conversion (from `const char[4]` to `Tekst`) but since you had no such conversion constructor, you had to add it.

Answer (score 0):

`Tekst t = "abc";` is just syntax sugar for `Tekst t("abc");` which means it does not even consider your `operator=` at all, it uses the class's constructor instead.

In order for `Tekst t = "abc";` to compile, you need a constructor that accepts either a `const char*` or a `const std::string&` as input. However, the constructor you showed takes a `std::string` by value instead of by const reference, so it can't be used for string literals.  So you need to add a new constructor for that:

```
Tekst(const char *_text) :text(_text) {};
```