# Binding references to string iterator in c++

Tags: c++, string, reference, iterator

When I tried to bind a reference to a string iterator it doesn't work

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string a;
    auto &i = a.begin();

    return 0;
}
```

But when i changed it to a reference to const it works

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string a;
    const auto &i = a.begin();

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this happen ?

Comment: I think this is an example of ["Most Important const"](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826897/why-not-non-const-reference-to-temporary-objects. But the correct thing to do here is to use a normal variable instead of a reference.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to do `auto &i = *a.begin()` to get a reference to the first character? A reference to the iterator doesn't make much sense