# Passing r-value as non-const reference (VS warning C4239)

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, rvalue

What I wish to do (using a C++ lambda) is effectively:

```
std::vector<MyType> GetTheArray () {return something;}

const auto DoSomething = [](std::vector<MyType> & array)
{
     //Some processing that involves either sorting the 'array' or setting temporary flags on the items
};

DoSomething (GetTheArray ());
```

This appears to be disallowed in standard C++ because the rvalue cannot be passed as a non-const reference.

My questions:

1) Is there a way to do this using a type-cast or am I obliged to create a temporary variable to store the results of GetTheArray ()?

2) Is there a good reason why this is disallowed in C++?

Please note that the 'something' returned from 'GetTheArray' is an array that is constructed on the fly, not a stored value.

Comment: Why would you want to sort a temporary array that will go out of scope as soon as your function returns?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4084053/951890

Comment: There are ways to trick the compiler into allowing this that don't involve the creation of a variable, but as al mentions, *why would you change a container that is going to die right away?*

Comment: 2 possible reasons:
a) I need to sort it in order to compare it to another array
b) I need to set flags on the data before passing it onto another function for processing (which in my case could be saving it to a database)

Comment: Thanks @Vaughn Cato.  I can see that there's some relevant information in that question.

Comment: In your code then, GetTheArray() is returning a temporary duplicate. Why not make it return a const reference to the original array, and then create a temporary inside DoSomething()?

Comment: I've added an explanatory note to my question about the 'something' that 'GetTheArray' is returning.  It appears that the cleanest standards-compliant solution to my problem however is indeed to pass the array by value and rely upon vector's move constructor.

Comment: The only difference is if you wanted to call GetArray() for read-only usage, you would be creating a temporary for nothing ;) if you return a const reference fro GetArray(), but make your lambda function take a value, you will still only get one duplicate of the original array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems from the comments that what you want is to take a vector, modify it destructively (in the sense that the original state cannot be reset) and then use the result internally. And you want this to work efficiently for both lvalues and rvalues.

The next question is whether in the case of the lvalue, the code that holds the original container needs it after the function call has completed, and if it needs the original state of the vector or not. Depending on the answers to that you have different solutions:

*The caller holding an lvalue does not use it anymore after the call*

*(or alternatively, the caller holding the lvalue needs the original state)*

This is the simplest case. Then your function should take the container by value. If the caller has an lvalue, it can `std::move` to avoid the copy (it does not care about the object anymore) or *copy* which might be more expensive but leaves the original container untouched.

If the function is called with an *rvalue* then the copy will be either elided or transformed into a cheap implicit move.

*The caller holding the lvalue does not need the original state, but it needs the container*

This case is the hard one, and you will need to provide two overloads for the same function (or lambda), one taking an *lvalue* to be used by this caller and a different taking an *rvalue-reference* for the case where the caller hands a temporary. In both cases the binding will be cheap. While this requires more code, you can implement one overload in terms of the other:

```
rtype f(std::vector<Data> & );   // for lvalues
rtype f(std::vector<Data> && v)  // for rvalues
   { return f(v); }              // v is an lvalue here
```

The fact that you are doing lambdas might make this slightly more complicated, but hopefully not too much.

Comment: Very interesting.  Yes, I get clean compilation by changing my lambda signature to take the array by r-value reference.  In your opinion, is this a "good" solution, or should passing parameters by r-value reference be reserved for move-constructors and move-assign operators?

Comment: @Coder_Dan: You should only use rvalue-references on the interface when you need to differentiate between lvalues and rvalues. Which is not limited to constructor/assignment, but to any operation for which you need that distinction.

Comment: @Coder_Dan: Not sure if it is clear enough, if you only provide the rvalue-reference overload, it will not accept an *lvalue* as argument, so you are limiting the use. If you start considering that for *lvalues* it is fine if the caller does `std::move`, then you should not take the argument by *rvalue-reference*, but by *value*.

Comment: Rodriguez - Thanks for the tip. I think I follow you, and see that if this function was in the public interface or I needed to accept an lvalue reference as well, then it would be preferable to pass the parameter by value.  You are also telling me that in this case, I can avoid the copy of the vector when passing an lvalue if I pass the parameter wrapped in a call to std::move, which is an interesting concept that I hadn't considered before. In my case, it's a function-local lambda that is called in the same way each time with different parameters supplied to the 'GetTheArray' function.

Answer (score 3):

If you for some reason you really want to modify `something` you could always copy the temporary into your lambda.

```
const auto DoSomething = [](std::vector<MyType> array) { /*whatever*/ }
```

The way you call your lambda a compiler might be able to elide the copy. C++11 move semantics formalize this.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  There should be no overhead of passing the 'array' by value in this case - obvious (well, should have been).

I guess that answers my specific problem, though possibly not for the more general case.

Comment: But there will be some overhead if you call with an lvalue as it will copy the container. Depending on whether this matters (or if the caller holding an lvalue cares about it anymore) you can take one of different roads...

Answer (score 2):

(Actually, @honk beat me to it as regards passing-by-value.  To be different, I'll extend my answer to discuss using `&&` explicitly)

Drop the `&`, and just pass it by value instead.

You're using lambdas, therefore you're using c++11, therefore you should just pass it by *value*.  Yes, it will be just as fast.

C++11 is very good at noticing when a temporary is being 'copied'.  It will replace the copy with a *move*.  It will then be fast, and arguably it will be easier to read.

So, even though you might know nothing about `&&` and `std::move` and so on, it's safe to say that you should start moving towards passing things by value instead of by reference.  It will lead to more readable code, and it shouldn't lead to a slowdown if used at the right time.

Basically, it's fast if you pass a temporary value, such as that returned by a function, into a function, *but only if you are using a standard container such as `vector`*.  Otherwise, you'll need to write your own `&&`-aware constructors to take advantage of the possible speed up.

**Update:**  If you're determined to force it to be by reference, and/or you are using custom containers, then you could replace `&` with `&&`.  This will allow you to pass a non-const reference.  This is called a *rvalue-reference*.

As has been pointed out by many others, the temporary will be destroyed just after `DoSomething` returns.  Bear this in mind.  It means that you will want to fully consume the contents of the array before it returns.  Maybe you print it to the screen, or store it in a database.  Alternatively, you might copy or move the data into another object and return that.

Answer (score 1):

You are handling a temporary returned from the `GetTheArray()` call in your bottom line. This can only bind to a const reference, and then the objec's lifetime will be extended to the lifetime of the const reference it is bound to (hence "binding").

Even if you could do what you wanted, your call to `DoSomething` would still be an expensive no-op. At the very least you'd need to `return` something from `DoSomething`.

C++ forbids this because (since C++11) it has rvalue references with move semantics, which can do awesome stuff, but not without returning *something*.

Comment: C++ forbid this well before C++11, so the last sentence makes little sense as it is written. *rvalue-references* (new in 2011) cannot be the reason that this was disallowed back in 1998, that is unless you believe in *anti-causality* for standard bodies.

Comment: Well, seeing as at least two major implementations implemented an extension (MSVC and Intel on Windows to be compatible with MSVC), there was a use for it. on the other hand, answering "why is it forbidden" questions is mostly solving the chicken and egg problem. I guess in this case @alexrider is right and it is to prevent no-ops like the OP's.

Comment: Two implementations allowed this, Solaris and VS, before the standard was written down. Then they were stuck with supporting this or breaking compatibility. Intel compiler specifically mimics the behavior of VS in windows and gcc on linux, so in their case it was again a need: being able to use the compiler as a drop in replacement for the native compiler. Still, *rvalue-references* cannot be the reason for disallowing this 13 years before they became standard. (At least in my simple mind, where time-travel does not exist and causality rules the world)

Comment: Thanks @David Rodriguez.  That's quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify `something` array you need to return a reference to it. Otherwise don't pass it by (non `const`) reference to `DoSomething`
The reason why it is disallowed is to avoid problems you are illustrating here. It looks like you are going to modify `something`, but instead copy of `something` returned by `GetTheArray()` will be changed. Which doesn't make much sense since this copy will be deleted right after `DoSomething` exits.
You have 3 ways to solve this.
1. You need to modify `something` then change `GetTheArray` to return reference
2. You need to modify copy of `something` that will be discarded `DoSomething` did it's job then change `DoSomething` to accept array by value.
3. You don't need to modify `something` in `DoSomething` then `const` reference as param of `DoSomething` should be used.

Comment: Thanks @alexrider - yeah, the 'something' that is returned is actually an array that is constructed on the fly and returned.  I guess I should have made that a little bit clearer.

I see what you're getting at though, there could be confusion (bugs) if it wasn't noticed that a simple accessor wasn't returning the value by reference.