# Trouble with: 'const int * const & alias_for_ptr = ptr;', why do both identifiers have different values?

Tags: c++, reference, alias, const-correctness

Im having trouble understanding the meaning of `const int* const &alias_for_ptr = ptr;`
with regards to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a = 10;

    int* ptr = &a;
    const int* const &alias_for_ptr = ptr;

    ptr = NULL; //or ptr = 0;

    if (ptr == alias_for_ptr)
        //This should execute but doesn't
        cout << "ptr == alias_for_ptr" << endl;
    else
        //This should NOT execute but DOES
        cout << "ptr != alias_for_ptr" << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Why is it that `ptr == alias_for_ptr` returns false, (in fact `alias_for_ptr` retains its old value of `&a`)? I was under the impression that `alias_for_ptr` will always have the same value as `ptr` (though the use of the & symbol) and that `const int* const X = Y` only ensures that I cannot change both the value of `X` and the value pointed by `X` through that identifier `X`.

Also if I remove the second `const` then the script will not compile, which confuses me futher. Note that the compile error is: `invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const int*&’ from expression of type ‘int*’`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which compiler are you using? I've compiled under MSVC++ 2010, and it works as you expect.

I think what's happening is a temporary is being assigned to a const-reference, since the type of "ptr" is converted from "int*" to a "const int*". What happens if you remove the first const?

EDIT: Read here for more on references: [Reference initialization in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315398/reference-initialization-in-c).

Comment: I think your right. Im using g++, if I remove the first const, then it works as expected, also if I add a const to the line above so its `const int* ptr = &a;` then it also works. Is there a way to do without adding/removing those two consts? I've tried using the `const_cast` operator but with no luck. Prehaps its a bug with g++.